# Importing javax.swing.JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, import, joptionpane

At the moment I'm following a book, and the current chapter gives you a brief look at GUIs.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
The MetricConverterWindow class lets the user enter a
distance in kilometers. Radio buttons can be selected to
convert the kilometers to miles, feet, or inches.
*/

public class MetricConverterWindow extends JFrame
{
private JPanel panel;                  // A holding panel
private JLabel messageLabel;           // A message to the user
private JTextField kiloTextField;      // To hold user input
private JRadioButton milesButton;      // To convert to miles
private JRadioButton feetButton;       // To convert to feet
private JRadioButton inchesButton;     // To convert to inches
private ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;  // To group radio buttons
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;  // Window width
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100; // Window height

/**
  Constructor
*/

public MetricConverterWindow()
{
  // Set the title.
  setTitle("Metric Converter");

  // Set the size of the window.
  setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

  // Specify an action for the close button.
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // Build the panel and add it to the frame.
  buildPanel();

  // Add the panel to the frame's content pane.
  add(panel);

  // Display the window.
  setVisible(true);
}

/**
  The buildPanel method adds a label, text field, and
  and three buttons to a panel.
*/

private void buildPanel()
{
  // Create the label, text field, and radio buttons.
  messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter a distance in kilometers");
  kiloTextField = new JTextField(10);
  milesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to miles");
  feetButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to feet");
  inchesButton = new JRadioButton("Convert to inches");

  // Group the radio buttons.
  radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
  radioButtonGroup.add(milesButton);
  radioButtonGroup.add(feetButton);
  radioButtonGroup.add(inchesButton);

  // Add action listeners to the radio buttons.
  milesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
  feetButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
  inchesButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

  // Create a panel and add the components to it.
  panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(messageLabel);
  panel.add(kiloTextField);
  panel.add(milesButton);
  panel.add(feetButton);
  panel.add(inchesButton);
}

/**
  Private inner class that handles the event when
  the user clicks one of the radio buttons.
*/

private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     String input;          // To hold the user's input
     String convertTo = ""; // The units we're converting to
     double result = 0.0;   // To hold the conversion

     // Get the kilometers entered.
     input = kiloTextField.getText();

     // Determine which radio button was clicked.
     if (e.getSource() == milesButton)
     {
        // Convert to miles.
        convertTo = " miles.";
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.6214;
     }
     else if (e.getSource() == feetButton)
     {
        // Convert to feet.
        convertTo = " feet.";
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 3281.0;
     }
     else if (e.getSource() == inchesButton)
     {
        // Convert to inches.
        convertTo = " inches.";
        result = Double.parseDouble(input) * 39370.0;
     }

     // Display the conversion.
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + 
              " kilometers is " + result + convertTo);
  }
 }

/**
  The main method creates an instance of the
  MetricConverterWindow class, displaying its window.
*/

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new MetricConverterWindow();
}
 }
```

This is a direct example from the book. I originally had this in a package titled window along with a few other GUI related classes. I decided to move it to default just to test something. Up until this point, I was just importing javax.swing.* instead of specifically javax.swing.JOptionPane, solely because its how the book has done the GUI examples up to this point. When I remove it from the window package and have it moved to default package, I get the error "The method showMessageDialog(null, String) is undefined for the type JOptionPane". If I add it back to my package for GUI examples I made, I have no issue. I've tried to word it every way I can think to, but I just can't find a solution as to why I get that error once it's removed from the package.

I realize I didn't quite get to the point of what I wanted to ask. What I'm trying to figure out is do I need to import both? It just doesn't make sense that It works fine in a package, but in the default it gives an error.

Comment: I'm wondering if you created another `JOptionPane` class, just as practice or something (in the default package). This would cause the error. IMO it's best to import all the classes individually though

Comment: I face no issues i running this code. what @peeskillet has pointed out might be correct.

Comment: I did read while attempting to find an answer online that it was considered poor habit to use the wildcard for this. It's also possible that I just have a book giving poor advice. I have no problem importing it individually, now I'm just curious as to what would cause it to work in a package I made, versus not. I checked all the classes in that package, and none of them imported JOptionPane specifically. @peeskillet

Comment: But did you create any class yourself that you named `JOptionPane`? That was my point

Comment: Ah, that is exactly what it was @peeskillet, I see what you mean now. Thank you! I had a practice class titled JOptionPane, which thanks to what I've learned, makes perfect sense now why it caused an issue.